# How to make a button permanently unclickable

Tags: java, android, android-button

I am making a log-in system on Android. And I want the register `Button` to be unclickable when it has been clicked. I am using this code:

```
final Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        register.setEnabled(false);
        Intent register = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), register.class);
        startActivity(register);            
    }
});
```

This is working great, but I want the `Button` to remain unclickable even when the application or phone has been restarted. Does anyone know a way to make the `Button` unclickable permanently even when the application has been shut down?

Comment: You could add a boolean to the SharedPreferences and check if the button has been pressed already, everytime you're creating it.

Comment: Your error is that **it is making the Button permanently unclickable**, but you are creating a new button every time the app starts!

Comment: @StackOverflowException He already knows that but he asked how to achieve that the button is disabled. As you can't ensure that the activity won't destroyed you have to save the state (button already clicked/or not) and check it everytime you create the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already said in the comments section something like this may work:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String KEY_IS_BUTTON_CLICKABLE = "key_clickable";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        final Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        boolean isClickable = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_IS_BUTTON_CLICKABLE, true);
        register.setEnabled(isClickable);

        if(isClickable) {
            register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    register.setEnabled(false);

                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit()
                            .putBoolean(KEY_IS_BUTTON_CLICKABLE, false);

                    Intent register = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), register.class);
                    startActivity(register);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You could simplify your code even further. If `isClickable` is false (when the user runs the app a second time, for example) simply don't call `setOnClickListener(...)`. That's a guaranteed way to make a `Button` unclickable. ;)

Comment: @Squonk Oh, of course! Didn't thought of that. I will change it. Tanks for the advice. ;)

Comment: @user3183005 This code works. Squonk just made an advice for an improvment. This improvment is already realized by now. I hope it meets your expectations. :)

Comment: Thanks, i believe you that the code does work, i will try it later, ill tell you if i meet any problems :) Thank you!

Comment: I am glad if I could help you. :) If it solves your initial problem please accept it as an answer so that others with a similar problem will find it more easily.

Comment: I am getting 3 errors (Link below). The first error says: "KEY_IS_BUTTON_CLICKABLE cannot be resolved to a variable". Erroe no.2 says the same and error 3 says: "Illegal modifier for parameter KEY_IS_BUTTON_CLICKABLE; only final is permitted". Please help me, Link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97063669/code.png

Comment: @user3183005 The last error is easy to fix. Just change the last line to: "private static **final** String KEY_IS_BUTTON_CLICKABLE = "key_clickable";"

Comment: @user3183005 Ah. You have to put the line outside the method. It's a instance variable. I've edited my answer to make it more clearly.

Comment: @user3183005 I fixed the errors in my answer and it should work now. I'm sorry for the intricateness I've wrote the initial answer from my smartphone.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers! Now i only got 1 error left ;) My error says: "The method putBoolean(String, boolean) is undefined for the type SharedPreferences". I took a screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97063669/lastError.png

Comment: Whoops. I'll take a look at that. I've written a class which handles all my SharedPreferences so it may be possible that this isn't a standard method. Wait a few minutes. :)

Comment: I solved it. :) .edit() was missing. I edited the answer. Now it should work finally.. :D

Comment: Thank you, im getting no errors now, but im sorry to tell that when i start my app it just comes a mesage "unfortunately locker has stopped". As i said, im new to this and have no idea why. :( Edit: Nevermind, i forgot the "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.pg2);". Thank you!

Comment: Glad that I could help. :) It would be nice of you to accept my answer so that others with a similar problem can find it more easily. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could take a pessimistic approach and disable the button in the layout (by default) with  android:clickable="false" and enable it in the condition where registration is required.